# Web server error code for browser not supported?

Tags: webserver, error-code

I know there is no such code defined by standards, but is there any standard error code used generally by people for browser version not supported, and if not, which is the nearest match that can be used for such scenarios: 415, 406, 501

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the intended client you can just invent your own status code. Else if the client is a web browser it won't make a big difference what you choose but 501 seam like the closest match.